# Load a csv file in R and share in all sessions?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application that uses a csv file to generate different figures. I upload my application in my personal linux server using shiny-server.
I use this structure for my application

- global.R
- ui.R
- server.R

Inside my **global.R** file I have this line, which help me to load and read my csv file

```
df <- read_csv("../Desktop/covid_2021-02-15.csv")
```

But my application is very slow, I read that objects in the global.R script, are read only one time and are share in all sessions.

Is there other way to load this data frame to have a more efficient application?

Comment: *"objects in the global.R script, are read only one time and are share in all sessions"* - this is correct. Therefore the only line of code you have shared has nothing to do with why your application is very slow.

Comment: What you can do is load the file, preprocess it (filter, aggregate etc.) to keep only what is needed by your app, then save the result. And load that result in new sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comments from Gregor and HubertL:

To load large CSV files can slow down. I had the same issue and changed to r binary file (rds) with `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`. As a first step you can try rds file and see if the issue is solved.
To check whether there is a performance difference you can use system.time(). Returns the time taken to evaluate any R expression.

In your case:

```
df <- read_csv("../Desktop/covid_2021-02-15.csv")
# Save an object to a file
saveRDS(df, file = "my_data.rds")
# Restore the object
readRDS(file = "my_data.rds")
```

Comment: qs is a faster replacement for saveRDS, readRDS. More general than fst. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qs/vignettes/vignette.html